# Can be used only in preamble occurs when using \usepackage command

Tags: errors, subfloats, algorithm2e

Whenever I am trying to use the `subfigure` or the `algorithm2e` package using `\usepackage` command, it is showing

```
LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
```

What is the problem and how to get rid of it. If there is any substitute for the two packages without using the above ones, kindly let me know.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you add a `\usepackage` command after `\begin{document}`?

Answer (score 9):

If your document looks like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\end{document}
```

then you get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \usepackage
               {subfigure}
?
```

showing that the problem is the `\usepackage` on line 5, which should be in the preamble (that is, before `\begin{document}`0 so changing the file to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

it runs without error.