# Use Packages not working on Tex Studio

Tags: packages

How do I eradicate this problem ? [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Don't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`: they both tackle the layout of enumerated lists, and will conflict.

Comment: You can only use `\usepackage` commands in the preamble of your document. So move there commands *before* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: As it currently is, your question look like a possible duplicate to [Can be used only in preamble occurs when using \usepackage command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277574/134144)